# Yaml To Json using Regex python

Tags: python, json, pyyaml

I just converted my Yaml file to Json with Python

/Stackoverflow telling me to put more lines of text so adding/

Yaml file here.

```
timetable:


subject1:
    day: Пн
    time: 08:20-09:50
    room: 0
    lesson: Физическая Культура
    teacher: Трифонов
    location: Онлайн
    parity: False
  subject2:
    day: Пн
    time: 10:00-11:30
    room: 11210
    lesson: Математика (Практические занятия)
    teacher: Игоревич
    location: д.9, лит.
    parity: False
```

Here is my converting code:

```
inputfile = open('saturday.yaml', 'r', encoding = "utf-8")
outputfile = open('timetable.json','w', encoding = "utf-8")
newline = inputfile.readline()
data = list()
lines = 0
list1 = list()
stringo = list()
while newline:
    data.append(newline)
    lines += 1
    newline = inputfile.readline()
inputfile.close()
start_k = len(data[0]) - len(data[0].lstrip())
outputfile.write("{\n")
for i in range(0, lines - 1):
    if data[i].lstrip()[0] == '-':
        list1.append('    "' + data[i].lstrip().lstrip('-'))
        outputfile.write('    "' + data[i].lstrip().lstrip('-'))
    else:
        stringo = data[i].lstrip().split(':', maxsplit = 1)
        outputfile.write('    "' + stringo[0] + '":' + stringo[1].lstrip())
    end_k = len(data[i + 1]) - len(data[i + 1].lstrip())
    if end_k < start_k:
        outputfile.write("  },"'\n')
    if end_k > start_k:
        outputfile.write('\n'"  {"'\n')
    start_k = end_k
outputfile.write('  }\n  }\n}')
inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Now I need to convert the file Yaml to Json using Regular Expressions and I am stuck there. Any suggestions?

Comment: but both languages are not regular

Comment: Which means it is not possible, right?

Comment: your link is dead btw ;)

Comment: Just use the [`yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) library

Comment: @makokinh00: it should not be possible in general using regular expressions